# Flex and Bison C adder gives error after not executing expression

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have been trying to implement a calculator, and I cannot find sources for this Flex, Bison and C program. I really can't tell what I'm doing wrong. Here are my files:

```
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ ls
a.out       compiler.output  compiler.y  lex.yy.c
compiler.l  compiler.tab.c   file.o      README
```

My grammar:

```
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ cat compiler.y
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  void yyerror(const char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
  }
  int yydebug = 1;
%}
%code requires
  {
    #define YYSTYPE double
  }
/*
%union {
    char c;
    char *s;
    double d;
}
*/
%define parse.error verbose
%define parse.lac full
%token NUM
%token PLUS
%token NEWLINE
%left PLUS
%%
answered: %empty      {;              }
| answered answer     {;              }//{ printf("%lg is answered.\n",$2); $$ = $1; }
;
answer: NEWLINE       { $$ = 0.0;    }
| expr  NEWLINE       { $$ = $1;     }
;

expr:  expr PLUS expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }//printf("%lg\n", $$ = $1 + $3); printf("Doing %lg + %lg.\n", $1, $3); }
| NUM                 { $$ = $1;      }//printf("%lg\n", $$ = $1);      printf("Found number: %lg.\n",   $1); }
;
%%
```

And my lexer:

```
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ cat compiler.l
%{
  int yylex(void);
  #include "compiler.tab.c"
%}

%%

[ \t]              ;

'\n'               ;//{ return NEWLINE;                                                                   }

'+'                { return PLUS;                                                                      }

^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? { sscanf(yytext, "%lf", &yylval); printf("%lf = %s\n", yylval, yytext); return NUM; }

%%

int main(const char **argv, int argc) {
  return yyparse();
}
```

I compiled it with these commands (I keep everything in my Downloads, and the folder name is an acronym, let's not worry about that too much):

```
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ bison --report=all --verbose --debug compiler.y
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ flex compiler.l
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

When I execute and type "5 + 5 [NEWLINE]" twice, I get:

```
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$ ./a.out
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 26):
-> $$ = nterm answered ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token: 5 + 5
5.000000 = 5
Next token is token NUM ()
Shifting token NUM ()
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 6 (line 34):
   $1 = token NUM ()
-> $$ = nterm expr ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 6
Reading a token: +5
5 + 5
5.000000 = 5
Next token is token NUM ()
LAC: initial context established for NUM
LAC: checking lookahead NUM: Err
Constructing syntax error message
LAC: checking lookahead $end: Err
LAC: checking lookahead NUM: Err
LAC: checking lookahead PLUS: S7
LAC: checking lookahead NEWLINE: S8
syntax error, unexpected NUM, expecting PLUS or NEWLINE
Error: popping nterm expr ()
Stack now 0 1
Error: popping nterm answered ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token NUM ()
Stack now 0
henry@FusionReactor:~/Downloads/YASPLANG$
```

I am very puzzled, and if it would be possible to tell how and why it will not work, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Your parser is parsing 5 + 5 as NUM NUM instead of NUM PLUS NUM, for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (f)lex, the pattern `'+'` matches a sequence of two or more <kbd>'</kbd>, because `'` is just an ordinary character. If you want to match a single <kbd>+</kbd>, use `"+"` or `\+` or `[+]`.

Similarly, `'\n'` matches the three-character sequence <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>. Just use `\n`.

Finally, `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` will only match a number at the very beginning of a line, because the pattern starts with`^`. You want it to match anywhere, so lose the `^`.

The reason no sensible error is reported is that (f)lex adds an implicit default rule which matches any single character and executes the ECHO action (which writes the character to `stdout`. That default rule is hardly ever what you want; I strongly recommend using

```
%option nodefault
```

to suppress it. You must then provide your own default rule, with a more sensible action.

Comment: I cannot get it to work, I tried editing grammar, and typing 5[ENTER]+[ENTER]5[ENTER], and just 5+5, it will not work. The code is here: http://pastebin.com/w54tnfGF thank you for helping me with this

Comment: @millenium I suppose you need to uncomment the commented-out code block which would return NEWLINE.